# AttachDbFilename in VB

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am made project in VB(Visual Basic 2010) so i am connection my project with data base with the following connection string in App.config :

```
  <connectionStrings>
  connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MY_DATABASE.mdf;Integrated Security=True; Connect Timeout=30"
  </connectionStrings>
```

but when i published my project by visual stdio and run the project after published to .exe the project did not run because AttachDbFilename is Error.

I am try to change the **

> AttachDbFilename to c:\Folder\MY_DATABASE.mdf

**

> but i received error : An attempt to attach an auto-named database for
>   file C:\Folder\MY_DATABASE.mdf failed. A database with the same name
>   exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC
>   shar

What i can do .

Comment: Did you distribute the MY_DATABASE.mdf file? And if yes in which directory did you store it?

Comment: In your connection string you say to the LocalDB version of SQLServer to use a file called MY_DATABASE.mdf where is stored all of your tables and data. Of course this database file should exists in the destination machine and should be stored where the |DataDirectory| substitution strings points to. See [Where is DataDirectory](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/where-is-datadirectory-)

Comment: this connection string from app.config as XML. code not VB Code

Comment: I am try to change the AttachDbFilename to c:\Folder\MY_DATABASE.mdf but i received error :                                             An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Folder\MY_DATABASE.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.  i need solution

Answer (score 1):

In you connection string just add the

```
'database=<database name> '
```

This prevents SQL server to create the auto-named database.

[Sources](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/192140/An-attempt-to-attach-an-auto-named-database-for-fi)

**Example further detailed:**

```
Dim myConnection As Sqlconnection = New SqlConnection()
 myConnection.ConnectionString="Server=server\serverinstance;Database=MYDbase;User Id=User1;Password=Pass1;"
```

Please change Server\Serverinstance to your Servers Data / mdf file

Please Change MyDbase to your database name / mdf file name

Change user and password to your username and password.

Edit 3: Try

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

And if that doesnt help here is everything on Conections

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: can you give me example about this please

Comment: i have not password or username so what i do,so note i am use local database not server sql

Comment: leave them out, delete the username password fields completely

Comment: this my connection string after editing "Server=(LocalDB)\mdf file;Database=MY_DATABASE"

Answer (score 0):

Connect VB Project with Service-Base Database via this code

firstly add Service Base Database

```
import system.Data.SqlClient
```

than
declare valriable for

```
Dim con as New SqlDataConnection
Dim cmd as new SqlCommand
Dim dr as SqlDataReader
```

in load event of form write code

```
con=New SqlConnection('Copy Path of the database');
```

find path of the database :

click on service base database

than in property you find the path copy that path and paste between ('')